# CoffeeScript: Overriding a method with (splat...) arguments

Tags: coffeescript

I'm stucked in trying to pass a splat forward to the super constructor. Something like this:

```
class Mom
    constructor: (vars...) ->
        [code]

class Son extends Mom
    constructor: (vars...) ->
        super(???)
        [code]
```

Well, question is:

**How do I call the super constructor passing along the son's received splat arguments?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`super` is super magical.

If you [just write `super`](http://coffeescript.org/#try%3aclass%20Mom%0A%20%20constructor%3A%20%28vars...%29%20-%3E%0A%20%20%20%20console.log%20%22constructing%20Mom%20with%20%23%7Bvars%7D%22%0A%0Aclass%20Son%20extends%20Mom%0A%20%20constructor%3A%20%28vars...%29%20-%3E%0A%20%20%20%20super%0A%0Anew%20Son%20%27a%27%2C%20%27b%27%2C%20%27c%27%20%0A%23%20Output%3A%20constructing%20Mom%20with%20a%2Cb%2Cc) it will compile to a call to the super-constructor forwarding all parameters, which is just what you want in this case :)

```
class Mom
  constructor: (vars...) ->
    console.log "constructing Mom with #{vars}"

class Son extends Mom
  constructor: (vars...) ->
    super

new Son 'a', 'b', 'c' 
# Output: constructing Mom with a,b,c
```

Answer (score 3):

`super vars...` is probably what you are looking for.

Comment: You can also call `super` with no arguments (and no parens) to call the superclass' implementation with the exact same arguments that were passed to the child constructor.

Comment: @IanHenry Good advice, but keep in mind that super with no arguments uses the `arguments` variable, so it will actually call it with the arguments of the closest scope (or function call).  So calling super from a callback that way will fail in pretty weird ways.

Comment: @AaronDufour Wow, great to know. That sounds like a bug in CoffeeScript to me, but apparently not to jashkenas... https://github.com/jashkenas/coffee-script/issues/1606

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to do a thing. The constructor actually uses only the `arguments` javascript variable. And that means, you can leave your call to `super` just as is.